# Javascript Date | Set date to the last second of year

Tags: javascript, date

In javascript I have a Date object with the following value:

```
Thu Jan 01 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Year could be anything, but day and time is always `Jan 01 00:00:00`.

Question: How can I set the date to the last second of the chosen year? 
In this example: `Dec 31 1998 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can instantiate the `Date` object with this format:

> new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);

Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
let date = new Date(1998,11,31,23,59,59); //note Month 11 is Dec (0 is Jan)
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a Date instance for midnight on the first day of the *next* year, then move the seconds back by 1.

```
var lastSecond = new Date(1999, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
lastSecond.setSeconds(lastSecond.getSeconds() - 1);
```

That's my general approach with JavaScript Date instances, but in this case because there are always 59 seconds in a minute and 59 minutes in an hour and 24 hours in a day, you could just directly create that target value with the constructor:

```
var lastSecond = new Date(1998, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59)
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the example date:

```
let date = new Date(2000,0,1);
```

And subtract one second from that:

```
date.setSeconds(-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always just remove `1000ms` from the first day of the year to get the last second of the last year :

```js
let januaryFirst = new Date('01/01/2000'),
    oneSecondbefore = new Date(+januaryFirst - 1000);

console.log(oneSecondbefore);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `endOf` method from Moment.js.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/